# create zip file using thunderbird api

Tags: java, javascript, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I am trying to create a zip file using following code...I have a folder like "D:\smad". i have 2 files in that. and i want to create a zip folder with the name "smad.zip". but i found some code for "Adding a file to a Zip archive".. here am doing like this

```
 var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].
       getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties).
       get("AChrom", Components.interfaces.nsIFile);

       file.initWithPath(file.path+"\\smad.zip");

 var file11 = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].
       getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties).
       get("AChrom", Components.interfaces.nsIFile);

       file11.initWithPath(file.path+"\\home.txt");


var zipWriter = Components.Constructor("@mozilla.org/zipwriter;1", "nsIZipWriter");
var zipW = new zipWriter();

zipW.open(file, PR_RDWR | PR_CREATE_FILE | PR_TRUNCATE);
zipW.addEntryFile(file11.path, Components.interfaces.nsIZipWriter.COMPRESSION_DEFAULT, file11, false);
zipW.close();
```

Using the above code zip file is not creating ...please help me out..whats wrong with this code...And also is there any other way to create a zip folder with the help of javascript..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for the above question....

```
    var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].
           getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties).
           get("AChrom", Components.interfaces.nsIFile);

           file.initWithPath(file.path+"\\smad.zip");


     var filenew = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties).get("AChrom", Components.interfaces.nsIFile);

           filenew.initWithPath(filenew.path+"\\home.txt"); 


    const PR_RDONLY      = 0x01;
    const PR_WRONLY      = 0x02;
    const PR_RDWR        = 0x04;
    const PR_CREATE_FILE = 0x08;
    const PR_APPEND      = 0x10;
    const PR_TRUNCATE    = 0x20;
    const PR_SYNC        = 0x40;
   const PR_EXCL        = 0x80;
    var zipWriter = Components.Constructor("@mozilla.org/zipwriter;1", "nsIZipWriter");
    var zipW = new zipWriter();

zipW.open(file, PR_RDWR | PR_CREATE_FILE | PR_TRUNCATE);
zipW.addEntryFile("home.txt", Components.interfaces.nsIZipWriter.COMPRESSION_DEFAULT, filenew, false);
zipW.close();
```